# Infinite Loop While Producing a Random 0/1 Output

Tags: loops, infinite-loop

Entry level comp sci major here.. I'm certain this question likely has an obvious answer, but I simply can't figure out why the following code produces an infinite loop and it's driving me insane. I understand that `Math.random()` returns a `double` value which when multiplied by 10 moves the decimal once to the right and the `(int)` typecasts the `double` data type to an integer by truncating the rest of the digits after the decimal point.. but then why on earth is the following code producing an infinite loop one of the `boolean` expressions will eventually produce a `true` value?

Now if I use `&&` instead of `||` in the loop, it will work just fine because the `&&` checks both expressions for a `true` yield prior to determining the outcome of the entire expression. Ah.. help..

```
int x; 

do {

    x = (int)(Math.random() * 10);

} 

while (x != 1 || x != 0);
```

Comment: That's just boolean logic. If `x == 1` then `x != 0` amounts to `true` and if `x == 0` then `x != 1` amounts to true. If one condition in an OR conditional amounts to true, then the whole thing amounts to true. On a side note, you can reduce the statement to `do { ... } while (x > 1);`

Answer (score 3):

It is actually quite simple: Your variable 'x' can not be two different integer values. It does not matter if your variable is 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 or 9. Your while condition will always be true and therefor your loop will always run forever.

e.g:

```
x = 0: (x != 1 => true || x != 0 => false) => true
x = 1: (x != 1 => false || x != 0 => true) => true
x = 2: (x != 1 => true || x != 0 => true) => true
...
```

Comment: But let's say hypothetically that x is assigned 1 by (int)Math.random()*10, and thus while (1 != 1 || 1!=0);

Shouldn't the 1 != 1 condition evaluate to false which in turn would evaluate the entire expression to false since || checks only one condition's true/false outcome and if the first is true, the entire expression is true. So my thinking is/was that if x is 1, then while (x != 1 | x != 0); is false since 1 != 1 is false thus causing the loop to end and console to print 1..

Comment: you are right about the evalulation logic of boolean expressions, the problem is that you are getting && and || wrong.
With && if the first expression is false then the second expression is not evaluated.
With || if the first expression is true the second expression is not evaluated

Comment: @Isildur01 `true || false` is true in boolean logic.

Answer (score 0):

a `while` loop continues *while the condition is true*.

The condition you wrote is trivially always true for any value of x.

And number is always "different from 0" or "different from 1" (or both).

Hence, the infinite loop.

---

Maybe you thought `||, the logical 'or', meant "either the first one or the second is true, but not both" ?

If you want to have "x != 0 or x != 1, but not both", then you actually meant `x == 0 || x == 1`

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand my erroneous thinking now.. with an || expression, if the first expression evaluates to false, the second is always also evaluated. I was under the impression that similar to &&, if one expression in an || is false, the entire is interpreted as also false, but turns out (false || true) = true while (false && true) = false as well as (true && false) = false, but unlike the ||, in an &&, the compiler doesn't even bother evaluating the second expression when the first yields false but an || evaluates both only if the first is false. I think I got it...